# Question about signs in the derivation of the free propagator for scalar field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, propagator

I have been going through Anothony Zee's quantum field theory textbook, and I am caught up on something that I think should be trivial, but I am not quite getting it to work out. The free propagator in Zee's book for free scalar field theory is 
$$D(x-y)=\int \frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{\exp[ik(x-y)]}{k^2-m^2+i\epsilon}.$$

Let y=0, so that we describe the propagation of a particle from the origin to x. To evaluate $D(x)$, we can perform a contour integration of $k^0$, to which there are two poles in the $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$ limit. Let us just focus upon the pole at $-\omega_k+i\epsilon$. Then we can choose a semicircular contour in the upper-half plane, so that we get exponential decay as we push the contour out to infinity. One has
$$D(x)=\int \frac{dk^0d^3k}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{e^{ik^0 x^0}e^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}}{(k^0+\omega_k-i\epsilon)(k^0-\omega_k+i\epsilon)}$$
$$=2\pi i\int \frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{e^{-i\omega_k x^0}e^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}}{-2\omega_k}=-i\int \frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^2 2\omega_k}e^{-(i\omega_k x^0+i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x})}.$$
But, for the upper half plane, Zee gets
$$D(x)=-i\int\frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^32\omega_k}e^{-i(\omega_kx^0-\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x})}.$$
From my previous runs with QFT, I know that the expression that I obtained cannot be correct, but I cannot seem to reconcile the sign difference between the two.

Comment: Since you integrate over all ${\bf k}$ arn't they the same expression.  In other words isn't $D(x)=D(-x)$?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. They are indeed!